# Implementing Movable <DIV>'s in jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins, jquery-selectors

I am trying to build a dynamic drag&drop module for my App.

It includes a table that holds all the droppable divs and few shapes.

As i can't know from advance the type of shape someone will put in a div and i have to save the div or divs which the user chose to drop the shape in i need to allow the app to be very dynamic...

I managed to do it for all the celld except from the top row for the big square and the long line and the right column for the big square and for a wide line....

The code:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title>Untitled Page</title>
    <style type=text/css>
     .draggable { width: 20px; height: 20px; background-color:Blue;}
     .draggable_big { width: 40px; height: 40px; background-color:Blue;}
     .draggable_wide { width: 40px; height: 20px; background-color:Blue;}
     .draggable_long { width: 20px; height: 40px; background-color:Blue;}
     .droppable { width: 20px; height: 20px; background-color:Red;}
 </style>
    <script src="JavaScript/jquery-1.4.2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="JavaScript/jquery-ui-1.8.4.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

        $(document).ready(function() {
            $(".draggable").draggable({ snap: '.droppable' });
            $(".draggable_big").draggable({ snap: '.droppable' });
            $(".draggable_wide").draggable({ snap: '.droppable' });
            $(".draggable_long").draggable({ snap: '.droppable' });
            $(".droppable").droppable({
                drop: function() {alert('dropped:' + $(this).attr('id')); }
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>

<body dir="rtl">
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div style="position:absolute; top:0; right:100px">
        <table border="1" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
            <tr id="tr_1" runat="server">
                <td  id="td_1_1" runat="server"><div id="1_1" class="droppable"></div></td> ***not getting responce for draggable_big***
                <td  id="td_1_2" runat="server"><div id="1_2" class="droppable"></div></td> ***not getting responce for draggable_big***
                <td  id="td_1_3" runat="server"><div id="1_3" class="droppable"></div></td> ***not getting responce for draggable_big***
                <td  id="td_1_4" runat="server"><div id="1_4" class="droppable"></div></td> ***not getting responce for draggable_big***
            </tr>
            <tr id="tr_2" runat="server">
                <td id="td_2_1" runat="server"><div id="2_1" class="droppable"></div></td> ***not getting responce for draggable_big***
                <td id="td_2_2" runat="server"><div id="2_2" class="droppable"></div></td>
                <td id="td_2_3" runat="server"><div id="2_3" class="droppable"></div></td>
                <td id="td_2_4" runat="server"><div id="2_4" class="droppable"></div></td>
            </tr>
            <tr id="tr_3" runat="server">
                <td id="td_3_1" runat="server"><div id="3_1" class="droppable"></div></td> ***not getting responce for draggable_big***
                <td id="td_3_2" runat="server"><div id="3_2" class="droppable"></div></td>
                <td id="td_3_3" runat="server"><div id="3_3" class="droppable"></div></td>
                <td id="td_3_4" runat="server"><div id="3_4" class="droppable"></div></td>
            </tr>
            <tr id="tr_4" runat="server">
                <td id="td_4_1" runat="server"><div id="4_1" class="droppable"></div></td> ***not getting responce for draggable_big***
                <td id="td_4_2" runat="server"><div id="4_2" class="droppable"></div></td>
                <td id="td_4_3" runat="server"><div id="4_3" class="droppable"></div></td>
                <td id="td_4_4" runat="server"><div id="4_4" class="droppable"></div></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
    <div style="position:absolute; top:0; right:50px">
        <div class="draggable"></div>
        <div class="draggable"></div>
        <div class="draggable"></div>
        <div class="draggable"></div>
        <div class="draggable_big"></div>
        <div class="draggable_wide"></div>
        <div class="draggable_long"></div>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Any one have any idea what is the problem?

Thanks

Comment: Can edit your question and clearly state what exactly you are trying to solve?

Comment: ok, i will try again, 10x....
In words over here:
Every time i try to put the: "draggable_big" class anywere it touched the edge of the dropable area (the top row and the right collumn) i dont get the alert with the id of the div, all other drops work great...I just dont understand what is wrong and why dosn't it work on those specific divs and all the other work fine

Answer (score 0):

solved the problem by adding:

```
$( ".draggable_big" ).draggable( "option", "cursor", 'move' );
$( ".draggable_big" ).draggable( "option", "cursorAt", {right:15,top:15} );
```

to every draggable object..

10x